# Error importing excel file via Aginity Workbench for Netezza

Tags: mysql, excel, netezza, workbench

I am using Aginity Workbench for Netezza.
I am currently trying to import an excel file into the database. The manual says I can import excel file via Tools -> Import -> from excel.
I tried the same, but it only shows limited columns. 
Which is, if my excel file has 3 columns, it only imports 2 columns, if mine has 4 columns it only imports 3 columns. 
I have checked all the options I could have limited the import columns but I cannot find out what is causing the problem. I checked 'import all columns' and also 'import all rows', too (just in case).

Did anyone have the same kind of problem and solve it? If so, please let me know how you fixed it. 
Or any expert's help will be so much appreciated.

I will be waiting for your help! Thank you

Comment: I've occasionally had odd things happen with this import when there are odd characters in the first line. Can you try changing the first line to be Netezza-valid names?

Comment: I have tried, but doesn't work anyway. but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you import the excel file using Import wizard of Netezza make sure you specify the start column and end column.[image]

Comment: I mean the maximum end column becomes 2 even when I have 3 columns. but thanks for your help.